# Mantaflow. Bake Mesh does nothing

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've been trying to find an answer online but it seems like the problem only happens to me :) The fluid simulation works well up until i try to bake mesh. This never results in any mesh, it takes time to bake but nothing gets added. The only thing that changes is that the bounding box automatically changes size to surround the particles as they move. I hope someone know what I've done wrong. / Alex

Comment: What do you mean "Bake Mesh"? Baked can be a cache, meshing has just a checkbox and is happening in realtime. What version of Blender you use?

Comment: Hello, could you add a few screenshots of your interface and how you setup your scene ?

Answer (score 2):

No mesh just bounding box.

Isn't that because you have set under
*Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display as >* **Bounds**?

[image]

---

*BTW - What happened to me (when I tried to confirm your issue) is that mesh was generated just around particles. In that case - **Save your file first.**
Under 2.92 if you change Resolution, Simulation method or probably any parametr which restarts cache should solve it as well.
In 2.83 LTS it was't even possible run simulation without saving a file.*

Comment: This did the trick! I thought is was supposed to be bounds to not block the simulation. Thank you :)

Comment: Please consider mark answer as accepted so others can see it from main list and also to stop system pocking question in periods as unsolved. Thank you keep this site organised. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour